# Why Does Pandas Convert the Timestamps to Huge Numbers when Dumping Json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime

This is how the sample pandas frame looks like.

[image]

The first column has `dtype` as `datetime64[ns]`. But when I convert the data frame with `to_json(orient='records')`, this is what I am getting.

```
 [{"date":1494547200000,"item_nbr":96995,"prediction":85.0903691434},
{"date":1494547200000,"item_nbr":99197,"prediction":110.2331549721},
{"date":1494547200000,"item_nbr":103501,"prediction":179.3874884163},
{"date":1494547200000,"item_nbr":103520,"prediction":150.7441153415},
{"date":1494547200000,"item_nbr":103665,"prediction":163.3215086129}]
```

What are those huge numbers for the `date`, where do they come from? I tried converting it with unix timestamp, but even for that it is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `date` column as `str` to avoid conversion to milliseconds:

```
>>> df1.astype({'date': str}).to_json(orient='records', indent=2)
[
  {
    "date":"2017-05-12",
    "item_nbr":96995,
    "prediction":85.0903691434
  },
  {
    "date":"2017-05-12",
    "item_nbr":99197,
    "prediction":110.2331549721
  },
  {
    "date":"2017-05-12",
    "item_nbr":103501,
    "prediction":179.3874884163
  },
  {
    "date":"2017-05-12",
    "item_nbr":103520,
    "prediction":150.7441153415
  },
  {
    "date":"2017-05-12",
    "item_nbr":103665,
    "prediction":163.3215086129
  }
]
```